# MYSQL Datediff between two dates based on year

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have two date columns say start and end i want to know the `datediff` from the 1st date of 2018. I'm working on mysql.

Here is my table

[image]

in the image odate is the start date and edate is the end date. Now i want to know total datediff for an emp_id in the year 2018.

Comment: Great. What have you tried. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I a `CASE ... END` return '2018-01-01' when `odate` is less than '2018-01-01' otherwise `odate`:

```
datediff(edate, CASE WHEN odate < '2018-01-01' THEN '2018-01-01' ELSE odate END)
```

Comment: i'm not that expect in sql so can you edit the query?

Comment: well both of your edits are not working for my two rows it's giving different results.

Comment: for the 1st row datediff need to return 5 and for 2nd row it should be for 4.

Comment: @Arpan: Another edit... Hopefully I guessed it right this time. If not, then please consider editing your answer and more clearly describe the rules that should apply here. Doing this only from an example is tedious.

Comment: this is the final query i made from your updated answer
SELECT datediff(CASE WHEN edate>concat(YEAR(now()),'-12-31') THEN concat(year(now()),'-12-31') ELSE edate END, CASE WHEN odate < concat(year(now()),'-01-01') THEN concat(year(now()),'-01-01') ELSE odate END)

Answer (score -2):

Say table name is tableA and column name of end date which you want to get diff from.

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(end_date) as datadiff FROM tableA,
```